# how to join tables which are different database . I have a items_table in brands database and products_table in products database

Tags: join

[table created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg7y8.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIK7V.png)

i have tried this , but it looks like its not working.
select it.*
select pd.*
from [dbo].[items_table] it inner join [dbo].[products_table] PD on it.items_id=pd.product_id

ERROR: Msg 107, Level 15, State 1, Line 25
The column prefix 'it' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference a table in a different database by prepending the database name to the table name, separated by a period.

```
SELECT it.*, pd.* 
FROM brands.dbo.items_table AS it 
INNER JOIN products.dbo.products_table AS pd 
ON it.items_id = pd.product_id;
```

Comment: feel free to set this as correct answer! :)